# The requirement is to trim the data that have MemberPromoID < 889452707 from Member Promotion table in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

There is a table in SQL server database named Member Promotion.
The requirement is to trim the data that have `MemberPromoID  < 889452707`.
that has total `327025368` number of rows for `MemberPromoID  < 889452707`. 
Occupied 74,698.297 MB Data Space.

**Index columns:**
idx_CardAccountID
idx_MarketingCodeSKN
idx_MemberID
idx_OnlineCertNumber
indx_UsedDateID
PK_MemberPromotion

Please suggest how to do it efficiently.
Performance wise better.

Comment: More appropriate for research on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your index columns, i can't tell if member promoid is part of any of those columns..But you can use this ordered delete technique

like below

```
create view v1 as (
select top (10000) * from t1 
where MemberPromoID  < 889452707
order by primary key column
)

delete from v1
```

The above query deletes in batches , you can run it in a loop and try using rowcount to delete all.Above technique is used by SQLCAT team,i am not able to find main source now

**Reference:**
http://web.archive.org/web/20100212155407/http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2009/05/21/fast-ordered-delete.aspx

Comment: member promoid is the Primary Key.

Comment: Please suggest in more specific if we can do it by creating TrimMemberPromotion Stored Procedure and if we can delete by using batch.

Comment: Go with above approach and use member promoid in order by

Comment: No need of stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to populate table t1 from table Member Promotion. Where Member Promotion table has 327025368 rows for  MemberPromoID  < 889452707

Comment: If I understood correctly,simple select * into t1 from other table would work

Comment: If we are deleting from view, how it will be deleted from main table. And if we need to delete 231 Millions records from main table?

Comment: You can delete from view ,if it affects only one table and u follow certain rules

Comment: I deleted 30 millions records using above approach. But remaining 1276 records are not deleting.I used below code: